# End Date cannot be less than Start Date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have dates in this format: dd-mm-yyyy

Start Date: 19-03-2014

End Date: 16-03-2014

I want to validate End date. It should not be lesser than Start date. I want to show an alert message in such condition.
I have tried following and its not working for me

```
if ($.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yyyy',to_date) > $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yyyy', from_date)) {
    alert(from_date + 'is later than ' + to_date);
}
```

I have also tried

```
var from = new Date(from_date);
var to = new Date(to_date);

if (to < from) {
    alert(from + 'is later than ' + to);
}
```

No Luck. Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

Comment: Your first piece of sample code has the comparison backwards.

Comment: Silly me!! It was the problem with comparison operator. Thanks @pointy

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if(Date.parse(from_date) < Date.parse(to_date)){
alert("message");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the date string manually and try this code:

```
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.split('-');
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]);
}

var from = parseDate("19-03-2014");
var to  = parseDate("16-03-2014");

if(to<from){
    alert(from + 'is later than ' + to);
}
```